# Car hesitant to start

Tags: starting

I’ve got a car that is hesitant to start.

3 weeks ago it broke down unexpectedly. The mobile mechanic squirted some engine cleaner into it which got the engine to catch, but it cut out again after about 3 seconds. He then replaced a blown fuse, which he said was related to the fuel system.

After that, car started fine for a couple of weeks, then began becoming increasingly slow to start (cranking fine, just taking longer than usual for engine to catch). Once it’s started, it drives fine, not rough at all. Got it looked at by the mechanics who checked for simple things (eg battery) and couldn’t find a cause. They thought it might be a fuel pressure problem and booked the car in for diagnostics. Over about a week it got slowly worse until at its worst, it wouldn’t start on the first try (but started ok on the second).

Got it looked at again, fuel diagnostics were run (fuel pressure was fine). They looked at the spark plugs and found two were worn, also dirty air filter. New set of spark plugs and new air filter installed. Car still having the problem, but now it is demonstrating poor power for the first 30 seconds (has almost stalled on one occasion).

3 different mechanics have looked at it in the past 3 weeks (and it was serviced 3 weeks ago).

Problem seems to be worse on starting for the first time after being left for a while (it’s currently summer - warm ambient temperatures outside, not living in a cold climate).

2011 Great Wall petrol manual 4WD, 83000km.

Suggestions?

Comment: It does sound like fuel, but they already checked that... It could be a dirty air temperature/air flow sensor (could cause trouble starting, and random power hiccups), or a bad spark plug wire (which would explain loss of power if it randomly bumped things).

The first thing I'd probably check would be the mass airflow sensor. (Or whatever they are currently calling the sensor in your air intake which tells the engine how much air you're getting, and what the air temperature is.) See if its dirty and needs to be cleaned, and maybe try cleaning it carefully.

Comment: did they do a compression test?